# Building template Stack structure with vector c++

Tags: c++, vector, stack

I am realizing a templated Stack structure on the base of *vector* in C++. I am not sure what is wrong with my code.

Stack.h

```
#ifndef STACK_H_
#define STACK_H_
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
template <class T>
class Stack {
public:
    Stack();
    virtual ~Stack();
    bool empty();
    int size();
    void push(T pushvar);
    T pop();
private:
    std::vector<T> container;
};
#endif /* STACK_H_ */
```

Stack.cpp

```
#include "Stack.h"
#include <vector>
//template <class T>

Stack::Stack()
    :container(0)
    {

    }

Stack::~Stack() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

bool Stack::empty(){
    return (container.empty());
}
```

Even before calling anything from the main, Eclipse gives me several errors. But I will give an exemplary main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Stack.cpp"
using namespace std;
int main() {
    Stack<int> s;
    cout << s.empty();
    return (0);
}
```

The compiler returns the following errors:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
'container' was not declared in this scope  Stack.cpp   /PracticeCpp/src    line 23 C/C++ Problem
'template<class T> class Stack' used without template parameters    Stack.cpp   /PracticeCpp/src    line 22 C/C++ Problem
invalid use of template-name 'Stack' without an argument list   Stack.cpp   /PracticeCpp/src    line 12 C/C++ Problem
invalid use of template-name 'Stack' without an argument list   Stack.cpp   /PracticeCpp/src    line 18 C/C++ Problem
Member declaration not found    Stack.cpp   /PracticeCpp/src    line 12 Semantic Error
Member declaration not found    Stack.cpp   /PracticeCpp/src    line 18 Semantic Error
Member declaration not found    Stack.cpp   /PracticeCpp/src    line 22 Semantic Error
Method 'empty' could not be resolved    Stack.cpp   /PracticeCpp/src    line 23 Semantic Error
Symbol 'container' could not be resolved    Stack.cpp   /PracticeCpp/src    line 13 Semantic Error
```

I know that I haven't realized all the methods declared in the header file, but this is not my problem. Before I continue realizing them I want to understand where am I wrong?

---

### Correction after the answers:

I followed the suggestions in the answers but still I don't get what continues to be wrong. I moved the template realizations to the header. I deleted the other unrealized methods to avoid confusion. Now my .cpp file is empty.
My new header file:

```
#ifndef STACK_H_
#define STACK_H_
#include <vector>


template <class T>
class Stack {
private:
    std::vector<T> container;
public:
    template <typename T>
    Stack<T>::Stack() : container(0)
    {
    }

    template <class T>
    bool Stack::empty() {
         return container.empty();
    }
};


#endif /* STACK_H_ */
```

Comment: Why the downvotes ?

Comment: On SO there's always (more than) someone that doesn't like the question or the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `Stack::empty()` was never declared, you declared `Stack<T>::empty()`. The same is true for each other constructor, operator and method. Add a template declaration to each implementation to fix this error. Notice that the error message hints at the mistake by saying "invalid use of template-name 'Stack' without an argument list".

Example :

```
template<class T> bool Stack<T>::empty() { 
     return container.empty(); 
}
```

Implementations for template methods should be included in header files. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).

Edit :

Regarding your newest example, you've mixed up two solutions. Try either :

```
#include <vector>

template <class T>
class Stack {
private:
    std::vector<T> container;
public:
    Stack() : container(0)
    {
    }

    bool empty() {
        return container.empty();
    }
};
```

OR

```
#include <vector>

template <class T>
class Stack {
private:
    std::vector<T> container;
public:
    Stack();

    bool empty();
};

template<class T>
Stack<T>::Stack() : container(0)
{
}

template<class T>
bool Stack<T>::empty() 
{
    return container.empty();
}
```

In the first solution, you are defining your functions within the definition of your class. The compiler knows that you are working on class `Stack<T>`, you mustn't remind it. In the second solution, the functions are defined outside the class. Here, you must specify which class' `empty` method and constructor you are defining.

Comment: Thank you. I added my corrected header in the end but there are still issues.

Comment: You've misunderstood my answer. It only applies when implementing methods outside of the class definition. Within the class definition (as you've done) you do not need to specify `Stack<T>::` every time, and you do not need to specify the template each time.

Comment: I am sorry but I got totally confused. Can you correct the header so that it works?

Comment: @Veliko Edited.

Comment: Now I got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

definition should be

```
template <typename T>
Stack<T>::Stack() : container(0)
{
}
```

And not in .cpp